# How to change a union function to a cut function? C# LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The session receives input as a list of streets.
* There is a table of streets, a table of countries, and a table that links countries to the streets.

Now the function shows me all countries that have one or more of the streets that the function received as input.
I need to change the function so that it displays only the countries where all the streets the function received as input.

I would be happy if someone could help me how I change the function.

Thank you

```
 entities
   .Countries
   .Where(c => c.Streets
     .Select(s => s.Id)
     .Intersect(streetsIDs)
     .Any());
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want, because the sentence *where all the streets the function received as input* isn't complete. Do you mean that the function should only return one country if all streets are in it?

Answer (score 0):

Take input `streetsIDs` and extract every element which is equal to any element in `Country.Street.Id`s (`Except` does that). If all the element is extracted, meaning `streetsIDs` is subset of `Country.Street.Id`s

```
entities
.Countries
.Where(c =>
    !streetsIDs
     .Except(c.Streets.Select(s => s.Id))
     .Any());
```